# Is there a way to jump to code for outlets / actions in Xcode (4.4)?

Tags: xcode, interface, action, builder, outlet

I've been looking at an .xib that someone else set up and it would be really convenient if I could, say, double-click on the properties / methods associated with outlets / actions to jump to the actual code where those are declared / defined. I've tried everything I can think of but so far to no avail. Am I right that there's no way to do that...?

To illustrate, say I've got a UIButton for doing a "reset". When I right-click on that in the Interface Builder (this is Xcode 4.4) I might see that there's an associated outlet called "resetButton" and an action mapped to "onReset". From what I can tell, the only way to find the associated code is to manually type those property / method names into a search box and look for that in the associated .h / .m (e.g. using the Project Navigator search). In some cases, I'm hitting the same names multiple times in different files then having to figure out which one is for the object that I'm actually interested in.

Is there some trick that I could use to jump to the code that I'm not seeing?

ETA